# Error converting bytecode to dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-multidex

I've been struggling with this error for too long now. I keep getting this error

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;

Can someone plese help? Thanks

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.helpapp_ovi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello update your dependencies to latest versions and add this:

```
android {
  dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Still getting the same error. I have a red line under implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' but I believe all com.android.support files have the same version 28.0.0

Comment: Can you check firebase versions are latest from here : https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.3.1. Gives me this error when I try to update :/

Comment: You added  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'  } to repositories under gradle file in root folder.

Comment: Can you check again this file as an example and compare with your ones : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/analytics/build.gradle

Comment: Thank you! Worked but still had a few issues. I migrated to androidx and everything was fine.